# Unable to locate an element error is coming when i am running the below piece of code

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
public class TestWebtable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2016/engine/match/981019.html");

        int i = 2;
        int rowNum = 0;
        while (driver
                .findElement(
                        By.xpath(".//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr["
                                + i + "]/td[2]/a")).isDisplayed()) {

            i = i + 2;
            rowNum++;

        }
        System.out.println("Total rows are : " + rowNum);

}}
```

---

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[20]/td[2]/a"}
Command duration or timeout: 40 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
System info: host: 'pc-PC', ip: '192.168.0.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: Can Anyone help me in this i am stuck on this i am new so not able to get it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2016/engine/match/981019.html");

    int i = 2;
    int rowNum = 0;
    while (true) {

        try {
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath(".//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[2]/a"));

            i = i + 2;
            rowNum++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Total rows are : " + rowNum);
```

Comment: The code which you have sent is not working its going on an indefinite timeout and after 15 mins it is giving me Error in communicating with the browser

Comment: Try this by skipping while loop    int x = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a")).size()   || Will return the count of batsman

Comment: Hmmm actually i need to do with while loop only, have you tried this code is this working for you

Comment: Then verify the element exists or not before isDisplayed() .Use try catch block in while look when exception is thrown break the loop (in catch block).

Comment: Can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

i tried but your code didn't work but anyways i googled and i found out this answer which is satisfying my needs :

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

```
 @BeforeTest
 public void setup() throws Exception {
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2016/engine/match/981019.html");
 }

 @AfterTest
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
  driver.quit();
 }

 @Test
 public void Handle_Dynamic_Webtable() {

  //To locate table.
  WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1][@class='batting-table innings']"));
  //To locate rows of table.
  List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
  //To calculate no of rows In table.
  int rows_count = rows_table.size();

  //Loop will execute till the last row of table.
  for (int row=0; row<rows_count; row++){
   //To locate columns(cells) of that specific row.
   List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
   //To calculate no of columns(cells) In that specific row.
   int columns_count = Columns_row.size();
   System.out.println("Number of cells In Row "+row+" are "+columns_count);

   //Loop will execute till the last cell of that specific row.
   for (int column=0; column<columns_count; column++){
    //To retrieve text from that specific cell.
    String celtext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
    System.out.println("Cell Value Of row number "+row+" and column number "+column+" Is "+celtext);
   }
   System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class TestWebtable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2016/engine/match/981019.html");

    int rowNum = 0;

    List<WebElement> lstElements = driver.findElements(By.XPath(".//*[@id='full-scorecard']/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class,'batsman-name')]/a"));
        rowNum = lstElements.Count;

    System.out.println("Total rows are : " + rowNum);
   }
}
```